# In Reeder for iPhone, how to add defaul recipients for sharing via mail?

Tags: iphone, google

In the app Reeder for iPhone, when I tap on: "Settings" > "Sharing Services" > "Mail", there appears to be a "Default Recipients" section, with four rows: "Link", "Article", "Text Selection", and "Image". Tapping on any of these rows doesn't seem to trigger anything.

Does Reeder allow one to set up default recipients for mail? How can I do that?

(This is on iOS 6. Reeder's version is 3.0.4.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. Don't tap on the actual word "Link" or "Article" etc... You need to tap the centre of the white space after the word. The keyboard will show up and you can type the default email address :)